# Facebook "like" feature with mongodb schema/endpoint design

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema

I came up with multiple solutions but none of them seems to be "future proof".

Let me iterate my solutions first.

**Acceptance criteria of the feature**

1. User can like or unlike a post
2. User can see "filled heart" on the post that he liked already

**Assumption**

There is User collection and Post collection

### Possible Solutions

**1. Put array of user references who liked the post.**

*Problem*

Super simple, but once "post" grows too much, all users that query    the post will be affected. Also putting potentially infinite    array in    a document.

**2. Put array of Post references to User**

*Problem*

Same with above, but only the user with growing data may be affected.

**3. Like schema with reference to User and Post and add counter to Post**

*Problem*

This document will grow very rapidly, many users will like many posts everyday. How do I query which posts a user liked? What if this collection grows to millions of like documents?

So far I have not found the right answer, at first, I thought #1 was way to go, then quickly changed my mind to #3, then I was like - what if it grows fast and becomes painful to query to find "likes" from millions of documents every time I fetch posts? Now I am thinking #2 is "safer" option but I may be wrong. If I go #3, I'd like to separate /likes and/posts endpoints, so that's another issue. - how will I query if a user liked from list of posts? Should it be separate singular endpoint? But it will be too many calls each time list of posts loads up. I am confused :(

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Door #3! Then your gonna use a unique compound index with User+Post to prevent duplicates and to have fast query times.

When you query posts your going to want to use an aggregate pipe so you can $lookup to see if the 'like' document exists for each post.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/index.html

Should get you started.

Comment: If this is the case, my posts endpoint will likely return "like" status which won't return pure Post object, now my service has dependency. How to get around this?

Comment: Right it will be added in the 'liked' boolean to your post object. But you can guarantee its existence by using a default value in your pipe.

Comment: If your determined to keep your Post object 'pure' you could query the like data in a single second request. Once the posts are received, map their _ids, then request all the like data at once, queried from db using the $in operator. I'd play with $lookup first though.

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for, SELECT WHERE IN array of postIds, but each ids will be fairly long, so when I query from client, won't it exceed url length limit? say, i initially received 24 posts, and I need to query "like" with 24 ids. how will I do this?

Comment: ```db.Likes.find({post: {$in: [array-of-ids]}});```

Where 'array-of-ids' is a param passed to your endpoint. If your posts perPage is only 10 or 20 you should be fine._id hexes are 24 chars. You can always send in the payload/body of the request though.

Comment: When you receive the response you'll do something like ```ids = posts.map(post => post_id)``` to get the array you need.

Comment: I see, I know get with req.body is a bad practice for http cacheing, so some suggests I use POST. but I misunderstood url length limit was only 256 characters, where it seems it is actually 2083, so i think i should be fine with query params. I will go with #3!! Lovely! Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217497/discussion-between-damian-and-gitgitboom).

Comment: Forgot to include the user in that query example. ```db.Likes.find({post: {$in: [array-of-ids]}, user: ObjectId(user-id)}); ```